# combine RxJs Observable array

Tags: angular, meteor, ionic2, rxjs, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to do infinite-scroll in a Ionic2+Meteor mobile app which lists the contacts. In the following code, findContacts() function returns 10 contacts at a time.
        contacts: Observable;

```
  findContacts() :Observable<Contact[]> {
    /* logic to pull Contacts is here ...*/
  }

  this.contactsSub =  MeteorObservable.subscribe('contacts', options).subscribe(() => {
      MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {
        if(!this.contacts) {
          this.contacts = this.findContacts();
        }
      });
  });
```

This code gets called every time the user scrolls to the end of the list and gets the next 10 contacts. But the propblem here is, it is not appending to the already listed contacts. It just shows the newly pulled 10 contacts. I tried Observable.concat, but it doesn't give disired results. When i tried mergeMap, it goes it indifnite loop and errors out.
Could you please let me know how to concatinate Observable array objects? Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm stuck with this issue for more than a week now.
Thanks.

Comment: With the following lines, it is replacing the existing contats every scroll end.

          if (this.contactsSub){
              this.contactsSub.unsubscribe();
          }

          this.contactsSub =  MeteorObservable.subscribe('contacts', options).subscribe(() => {
              MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {
                  if(this.contacts) {
                      this.contacts = this.contacts.concat(this.findContacts());
                  } else {
                      this.contacts = this.findContacts();
                  }
             });
          });

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by changing contacts as an Array

```
contacts: Array<any>= []
findContacts() :Observable<Contact[]> {
    /* logic to pull Contacts is here ...*/
  }

  this.contactsSub =  MeteorObservable.subscribe('contacts', options).subscribe(() => {
      MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {
          this.findContacts().subscribe(data => {
                this.contacts = this.contacts.concat(data);
        });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Sudheer for the update. It seems like subscribe function cannot be used on findContacts. But based on your code sample, I tried the following

        this.contacts = this.contacts.concat(this.findContacts());

This seems to be not throwing any error. I also remove the unsubscribe call which i had above subscribe seems to keep adding the data to existing Observable<Contact[]>. But, it seems like works fine only upto 300 records/contacts. After that, it seems to freeze the application. I'm not sure if there is any limitation on infinite-scroll.

Comment: Longest possible array could have 232-1 = 4,294,967,295 = 4.29 billion elements. So it is not related to typescript array max size. It may be some other reason.

Comment: With the following lines, it is replacing the existing contats every scroll end.

          if (this.contactsSub){
              this.contactsSub.unsubscribe();
          }

          this.contactsSub =  MeteorObservable.subscribe('contacts', options).subscribe(() => {
              MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {
                  if(this.contacts) {
                      this.contacts = this.contacts.concat(this.findContacts());
                  } else {
                      this.contacts = this.findContacts();
                  }
             });
          });